# Summation with inequalities

Tags: summation, inequalities

How can I perform this function with Mathematica?

$$\sum_{1\le j<k\le N}\frac1{\left(r_{jk}\right)^\alpha}$$

where `n = 5`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
n = 5;
Sum[1/r[j, k]^α, {k, 1, n}, {j, 1, k - 1}]
```

> r[1, 2]^-α + r[1, 3]^-α + r[1, 4]^-α + 
>    r[1, 5]^-α + r[2, 3]^-α + r[2, 4]^-α +
>    r[2, 5]^-α + r[3, 4]^-α + r[3, 5]^-α + 
>    r[4, 5]^-α

Alternatively,

```
Sum[Boole[1 <= j < k <= n]/r[j, k]^α, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}]
```

> r[1, 2]^-α + r[1, 3]^-α + r[1, 4]^-α + 
>    r[1, 5]^-α + r[2, 3]^-α + r[2, 4]^-α +
>    r[2, 5]^-α + r[3, 4]^-α + r[3, 5]^-α + 
>    r[4, 5]^-α